# How to do this definite integration?

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

I was asked $$\int_a^b\! \frac{dx}{\sqrt{(x-a)(b-x)}}$$ I was surprised when I checked my answer. I can't upload my solution as the picture size us more than 2mb. But I am getting $\tan^{-1}b-\tan^{-1}a$. I don't know why. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The value of the integral is independent of $a$ and $b$. Let $x = a + (b - a)t$. Then $x - a = (b - a)t$ and $b - x = (b - a)(1 - t)$. Since  $t = 0$ when $x = a$, $t = 1$ when $x = b$, and $dx = (b - a)\, dt$, we obtain

$$\int_a^b \frac{dx}{\sqrt{(x - a)(b - x)}}\, dx = \int_0^1 \frac{(b - a)\, dt}{\sqrt{(b - a)^2t(1 - t)}} = \int_0^1 \frac{dt}{\sqrt{t - t^2}}.$$

Note $t - t^2 = (1/4) - (t - 1/2)^2$. So letting $t - 1/2 = (1/2)\sin \theta$ results in

$$\int_0^1 \frac{dt}{\sqrt{t - t^2}} = \int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \frac{(1/2)\cos \theta\, d\theta}{(1/2)\cos \theta} = \int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} d\theta = \pi.$$

Comment: Just to complete it, $$\int_{0}^{1}t^{-1/2}(1-t)^{-1/2}\,dt = \Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2=\pi.$$

Comment: Using the Gamma function seems like overkill in this situation. Unless there is a simple way to prove those equalities?

Comment: Like I said, use a trig substitution to finish the job.

Comment: I like your way of doing it, and I just want to suggest/mention another substitution, that might give a simpler integral (or, if you want, one that you directly recognize): Let $x=\frac{a+b}{2}+\frac{b-a}{2}t$. This sends $x=a$ to $t=-1$ (instead of zero) and $x=b$ to $t=1$, and the resulting integral becomes $\int_{-1}^1\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}\,dt=\arcsin 1-\arcsin(-1)=\pi$.

Comment: @mickep that's a good substitution, thanks for sharing. :-)

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

Set $x=a\cos^2t+b\sin^2t$

$x-a=a\cos^2t+b\sin^2t-a=\sin^2t(b-a)$

$b-x=b-[a\cos^2t+b\sin^2t]=(b-a)\cos^2t$

Comment: I made a slight edit to your answer, since you misplaced a dollar sign. I hope you don't mind.

Comment: @RoryDaulton, On the contrary, I want to thank you